# symbolic breakpoint - link to local code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've created an iOS framework that I've integrated in a simple test project. Now, I want to dd `symbolic breakpoints` in this SDK. So, I add it using Xcode's `symbolic breakpoints`[see attached image]. Now, when it hits the symbol, the execution stops - but, I see only `symbols` [image attached]. How can I link these symbols to the local code that I've for this framework?

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/xcode-breakpoint-wizardry/

Comment: does not help much.